# searching record in database having O'NEILL name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which having record which is of string type with name O'NEILL and while searching using query when i use following query:

```
select * from street_list where str_name='O'NEILL AVE'
```

I did get following error:

> 12:00:16  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 933, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can you please guide me how can I search the record in my DB. I m using oracle 11 g.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select * from street_list where str_name='O''NEILL AVE'
```

e.g.

```
with street_list as
(select 'O''NEILL AVE' as str_name from dual)
select * from street_list where str_name = 'O''NEILL AVE'
```

Comment: Please check for upper case, blank character. As you can see with my second sql it should work

Comment: @user12495 to be sure, you can try: `WHERE UPPER(TRIM(str_name)) = 'O''NEILL AVE'` which will avoid blanks and case differences as Frank said .

Comment: no dude i'm not getting result with select * from street_list where str_name like 'O''NEILL AVE%' or select * from street_list where str_name like 'O''NEILL AVE%'

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the exact matching data so you can use query in the following way:

```
select * from street_list where str_name like 'O''NEILL AVE%'
```

Comment: doubling the apostrophes solved it. remove the %. problem is not that.

Comment: This query is not fetching result why ? select * from street_list where UPPER(TRIM((STR_NAME || ' ' || STR_TYPE))) like UPPER(TRIM('O``NEILL AVE%'))

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from street_list where str_name='O''NEILL AVE'
```

This query is working fine. As you said in your record string type with name O'NEILL and in Where condition your Passing O'NEILL AVE. please check properly. If in record the name string is O'NEILL and your passing O'NEILL AVE then your query is not fetch the record for that you need to write query like this

```
select * from street_list where str_name='O''NEILL'
```

Comment: What is the problem with this query ? select * from street_list where UPPER(TRIM((STR_NAME || ' ' || STR_TYPE))) = UPPER(TRIM('O``NEILL AVE'))

Comment: please mention which database your using like Sql, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use escape quotes.

Here is another example to clarify:

`select '''Today is '' '|| sysdate from dual
'Today is ' 06/09/16`

Answer (score 0):

select * from street_list where str_name='O%NEILL AVE'

This works for both MySQL and MicroSoftSQL
Remember % is an (1) unknow replacement for a (1) letter or symbol or number ...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.